# Finding the top-most face/polygon(s) in a 3D geometry

Tags: javascript, 3d, geometry, mesh

Given a 3D geometry that may have flipped normals (but is otherwise valid), how would you find the top-most face/polygons(s), the ones which have no others above them?

For example, finding the orange faces in the following circumstances (showing a slice through the geometry):
[image]

As things stand, my current (woefully complex) approach is as follows:

1. Loop through all vertices and find the maximum Y (height) value (ie. find the highest point in the geometry – nothing can be higher)
2. Loop through all polygons and collect ones that have a vertex with the maximum Y value (ie. all the highest faces, though some may be on top of others – see image above)
3. Loop through the collected polygons and find the one with the largest absolute Y normal (ie. find the polygon that has the shallowest angle from horizontal – from what I can see this will always be on top of everything else in a valid geometry)

Aside from being unsure if this even works in all circumstances, I'd be interested to see if there's a more efficient way to approach this in either pseudo-code or JavaScript.

If it helps, the 3D geometry is stored as an array of polygons, which are themselves an array of point arrays:

```
[[[x,y,z], [...]], [[x,y,z], ...], ...]
```

Comment: I think you need to define what it means for a face *F* to "have no others above [it]." If you mean there is no other face *F'* that contains a point that is strictly higher than any point on *F*, then your 3rd step is unnecessary. If you means something else by "on top of everything else," then it needs to be spelled out to ensure you are matching your algorithm matches your intuitive definition.

Comment: Good point. "Have no others above it" is probably a human way of describing it, though what I mean is that if you projected a line straight up from each face connected to the highest Y vertex, that line wouldn't hit another face (ie. clear line-of-sight to the sky). In practice, this is to rule out cases like the second example in the above image, where there are 3 faces that are connected to the highest vertex (1 facing the viewer), yet one of those faces is underneath the true top (in orange), and the other is vertical (normal wouldn't be above the horizontal).

Comment: It also matters if your faces form a simple, closed polyhedron. Much is hidden in your "valid geometry" phrase.

Comment: In this case, "faces" are valid, closed planar polygons (not triangles). Everything about the solid geometry is valid aside from there potentially being incorrect normals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the notion of topmost is not so clear.
Only those two low edges incident to the horizontal base have a
"clear line-of-sight to the sky."

---

[image: TopMostCex]

---